# Skeleton category of the category of skeleton categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-picture, higher-category-theory

A category is a **skeleton** if, roughly speaking, no two distinct objects within the category are isomorphic. To every category is associated a skeleton, and two categories are categorically "equivalent" if and only if their skeletons are isomorphic. A fuller definition can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_%28category_theory%29).

Consider the subcategory of $\bf{Cat}$ which takes as objects those categories which are skeletons, and morphisms the functors between them; I will call this $\bf{{Cat}_{Skel}}$. Note that this is not the skeleton of $\bf{Cat}$ itself, but a subcategory of $\bf{Cat}$ in which the *objects* are skeletal categories.

Within this subcategory of skeletal categories, there are a number of objects which are, themselves, isomorphic. So we can take the skeleton of this category, hence obtaining a new category, which I will call $\bf{Skel({Cat}_{Skel})}$. (I don't care which skeleton you take; pick one.)

This category is noteworthy in that it contains one object for each [*equivalence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) class of categories in $\textbf{Cat}$, making it perhaps more useful than looking at $\bf{Skel({Cat})}$ itself, which only contains one object for each [*isomorphism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_of_categories) class of categories. My questions are:

1. Does $\bf{Skel({Cat}_{Skel})}$ have a name?
2. Has this category been studied in any detail, and if so, can someone please reference me towards any research that's been done on its structure?
3. Is there an essentially equivalent construction which might be defined more simply than the way I've laid it out here?
4. Are there any useful areas of study in which this category naturally arises?

Lastly, I've glossed over the usual foundational issues which arise when considering $\bf{Cat}$, mostly because I don't care whether you use Grothendieck universes, or a class-set theory, or only look at small categories, or some other way of solving the problem. Feel free to use any foundational approach that you want which makes $\bf{Skel({Cat}_{Skel})}$ to be consistent.

Comment: +1: this is a nicely worded and interesting question

Comment: This is the same as the homotopy category associated to the canonical model structure on Cat. See, for example, http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/the-canonical-model-structure-on-cat/

Comment: Mike, can you explain your description of Skel(Cat_Skel)? Why does it contain equivalence classes of categories?

Comment: A skeletal category has "morally" as many non-trivial isomorphisms as its original category --- we are removing only isomorphic copies of objects; isomorphisms on objects have to be untouched. I am by no means an expert in higher-dimensional categories, but I would call your construction a 2-skeleton of a 2-category, where by a "2-skeleton" I mean a 2-category whose equivalent objects are equal.

Comment: What you're asking about is just the problem of when two categories are equivalent, but phrased in a sophisticated way.

Comment: Dylan: thanks, this looks very much in line with what I was hoping to find!

Comment: Martin: I mean this concept of equivalence of categories here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories

For any category C, you can impose an equivalence relation on Ob(C) such that two objects are equivalent iff they are isomorphic; they are then said to share an "isomorphism class."

For instance, if you do this with the category of real vector spaces, you end up with equivalence classes containing R^1, R^2, R^3, etc. Each equivalence class consists of a collection of vector spaces of the same dimension which are isomorphic.

(cont'd)

Comment: ...A skeleton of C is a subcategory which contains exactly one representative member from each isomorphism class and no other objects; as many morphisms on the objects remaining are exactly those which existed on those objects in the original category.

Skeletons need not be unique, but all of the skeletons of a category are isomorphic. In general, two categories are categorically equivalent iff their skeletons are isomorphic; a skeleton is thus representative of a class of equivalent categories. (contd)

Comment: ...Given that, Cat_skel is the category of all skeletal categories, some of which "represent" the same equivalence class. I'm interested in a category with exactly one representative per class of equivalent categories, so Cat_skel won't fit the bill by itself, as multiple skeletons for the same equivalence class are different objects. However, to solve this problem, we merely look at skeletons of Cat_skel! Now we have exactly one representative object per class of equivalent categories. This is interesting in the same way that Von Neumann cardinals are, hence the motivation for my question.

Comment: I like this question. I would bicker, however, with the first sentence. In general, a skeleton may contain _lots_ of nontrivial isomorphisms. They just all must be automorphisms. A category with _no_ nontrivial isomoprhisms is "gaunt" http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category.

Comment: "Now we have exactly one representative object per class of equivalent categories." So is this because two skeletal categories are isomorphic iff they are equivalent?

Comment: Martin: yes, but more generally, two categories are equivalent iff their skeletons are isomorphic.

Comment:   If $F: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ is a functor then is naturally defined  $Sk(F): Sk(\mathcal{A})\to Sk(\mathcal{B})$, then the inclusion $Cat_{Sk}\subset Cat$ induce $\iota: Sk(Cat_{Sk})\to Sk(Cat)$. We have a evident functor $j: Sk(Cat)\to Sk(Cat_{Sk})$ (from a small category take its skeleton, the its isomorphic element of $Sk(Cat_{Sk})$). We have  $j\circ \iota=1$, $\iota\circ j\cong 1$. THen I find this construction, no very interesting.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd So a gaunt thin category is skeletal, eh? More seriously, in the thin-gaunt-skeletal-poset quadfecta it seems like we have thin+gaunt->skeletal and thin+skeletal->poset, so thin+gaunt->poset as well. Are there any others that occur to you off the top of your head? Being super pedantic, it seems like defining a poset category to be a thin gaunt category is better than the current nlab definition as a skeletal thin category.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for in an answer, but maybe I'll flesh out my comment.

It looks like what you're describing is equivalent to the homotopy category associated to the model structure on Cat where the weak equivalences are equivalences of categories. (I can say "the" because there is only one such, as pointed out in the comments. The cofibrations are functors injective on objects, and the fibrations are "isofibrations".)

I would say that in this context your category has been much studied. In particular, it is interesting to ask questions about homotopy limits and colimits in this category because many useful constructions arise in this way. (Homotopy (co)limits with this model structure are the same as "2-(co)limits" which is the name appearing in most of the literature, especially older literature.)

An example application of this language is the following theorem: The subcategory of presentable (resp. accessible) categories is closed under homotopy limits.

Using this one can prove that most of your favorite things are presentable (resp. accessible). For example, the category of modules over a monad arises via a homotopy limit construction, and this takes care of most things of interest.

Here's a neat application of this (which is the ordinary category version of a result that can be found, for example, in Lurie's HTT, 5.5.4.16.).

Say you want to localize a category $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to some collection of morphisms, $S$. Usually $S$ will not be given as a set, but if $\mathcal{C}$ is presentable you're usually okay if $S$ is *generated* by a set. Well, it turns out that if $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is a colimit preserving functor between presentable categories, and $S$ is a (strongly saturated) collection of morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ that is generated by a set, then $f^{-1}S$ is a (strongly saturated) collection of morphisms generated by a set. The argument goes by way of showing that the subcategory of the category of morphisms generated by $f^{-1}S$ is presentable, using a homotopy pullback square.

Adapting this to the model category or $\infty$-category setting, one sees immediately that localizing with respect to homology theories is totally okay and follows formally from this type of argument. (Basically, after fiddling around with cells to prove the category of spectra is presentable, you don't have to fiddle any more to get localizations. This is in contrast to the usual argument found in Bousfield's paper. You've moved the cardinality bookkeeping into a general argument about homotopy limits of presentable categories.)

Anyway, apologies for the very idiosyncratic application of this language; these things have been on my mind recently. I'm sure there are much more elementary reasons why one would care about using the model category structure on Cat.